# Hybrid Mobile App: Difference between PhoneGap and Cordova

Tags: cordova

Hybrid Mobile App: Difference between PhoneGap and Cordova:

I know PhoneGap offer PhoneBuild service to build app for you and it uses a version of cordova BUT are there any other benefits which people have found using PhoneGap over cordova?

Comment: no, that's the only one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Phonegap**
Officially supports iOS, Android, Blackberry and Win
Cordova + You choose UI framework (Kendo UI etc.)
More UI work: Might take longer create a slick looking UI
We choose structuring patterns (MVC and angular etc.)
Cordova version not naturally angular friendly
NFC support via third-party plugin (PhoneGap-nfc). Need to test!
On-line build service available. Local option requires SDK’s and hardware
Command-line support: Which should enable CI
First-party app for testing “PhoneGap”
Backed by reputable company “Adobe”
Free (On-line build service is subscription based)

**Cordova**
Officially supports iOS, Android, Blackberry, Win, Amazon and Firefox
Cordova + You choose UI framework (Kendo etc.)
We choose structuring patterns (MVC and angular etc.)
NFC support via third-party plugin (PhoneGap-nfc). Need to test!
Backed by an Open-source group\community
No on-line build service available. Local option requires SDK’s and hardware.
Command-line support: Which should enable CI
No first-party app for quick testing
Free
Exclusive Cordova plugins

Answer (score 13):

PhoneGap and Cordova can usually be used interchangeably. They both allow you to build mobile apps with HTML, CSS & JavaScript.

[Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) is an open source project. [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) is Adobe's distribution of Cordova. PhoneGap is powered by Cordova but has a separate command line tool.

[PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) is a **service** provided by Adobe. With PhoneGap Build, you upload your HTML, CSS and JavaScript to Adobe's servers and they build native applications for you. The major benefit is that you don't have to have the native SDKs installed on your computer. This lets you do things like build iOS application from Windows.

Any JavaScript framework that works with Cordova will work equally as well with PhoneGap and PhoneGap Build.

You can use the same Cordova plugins across Cordova, PhoneGap and PhoneGap Build.

Plugins are installed with the command line tools on Cordova and PhoneGap.

```
phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-ble-central

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ble-central
```

If you're using PhoneGap Build, you install plugins by editing config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-ble-central" source="npm" />
```